# applying -webkit-tap-highlight-color to blank causes glitch in phonegap application

Tags: css, user-interface, webkit, cordova

Inorder to remove the problem of link hightlighting orange or blue for phonegap html5 application I had applied the property in my css as below...

```
**FOR INPUT TEXTBOX**
input
{
   -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
}
**FOR ALL ELMENTS WITH TAPS**
*:hover, *
{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

But for Some devices espcially HTC x One phone its causing UI problems. as attached screenshots.
[image: sample issue 1]
[image: sample issue 2]

Some workaround is given here but I want to try the CSS solution first. if avaiable.
http://samcroft.co.uk/2012/alternative-to-webkit-tap-highlight-color-in-phonegap-apps/

THankx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try going through this link . Video also helps to get a pre conception of what can be achieved

[webkit tap color](http://samcroft.co.uk/2012/alternative-to-webkit-tap-highlight-color-in-phonegap-apps/)